# asp.net drop down box selected index changed event does not fire when currently selected item is clicked

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, drop-down-menu, dropdownbox, selectedindexchanged

Here is a problem with the way a drop down box works. There is no event for clicking on an already selected item. In the asp.net code behind either C# or VB, the only event that can be triggered is SelectedIndexChanged. I have seen similar posts, but I haven't seen the question stated in the following manner.

I have a situation where for design purposes, I want a drop down list to list all the items only when the box is clicked. This box will allow a customer to add a product to an existing list or create a new list. I want the box to originally state: **ADD TO LIST**. But when the user clicks the drop down, **ADD TO LIST** appears in the drop down list as well as being in the original box!

**ADD TO LIST** has no functionality as the following items in the list have the options to: **Create new list** ; **List A** ; **List B** ; etc.

There is no way I can find to hide **ADD TO LIST** in the displayed drop down.

If instead I just use **Create new list** as the first item in my list, I am unable to select **Create new list** from the drop down list as it is already selected and will not fire the SelectedIndexChanged event.

There should be some way to either fire an event when an already selected item is clicked, or there should be some way to hide the first item from appearing in the drop down list as well as still appearing in the box above the list.
[image: dropdownbox]

I have tried tying an onclick event to the dropdownbox with jquery and I have also tried the onchange event but nothing worked.

Is this something for a future release or does someone have a workaround?

Comment: please post your code for reference.

Comment: Why not make a "Select here..." option as the first choice in the DropDown. In the postback event just set the `SelectedIndex` to zero and the user can select another option an the `OnSelectedIndexChanged` event will fire again.

Comment: I don't think you understand that it never gets to the postback event if the user tries to select the first item in the list since it has already been selected. I found a workaround as stated below.

Comment: I mean like this `<asp:ListItem Text="Select item..." Value=""></asp:ListItem><asp:ListItem Text="Add to Project" Value="1"></asp:ListItem><asp:ListItem Text="Add to New Project" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>`. Now the user will always have to choose an item that is not the first, thus firing the event. And by leaving the first value empty you can add a `RequiredFieldValidator` to the DropDown.

Comment: I also have to follow the graphic department's style guidelines. I need the box displayed on the website with a clear direction for the user. Hence the Add to Project as the first item in the list. Now when the user clicks the drop down box, the user should see the options available which should include ADD to NEW PROJECT (which I have changed to Create New Project) and a list of all current projects.

Comment: I don't want "Select Item" displayed again in the list of options for the user to click. It is not aesthetically pleasing. I fixed this by adding a class to the first item which caused it to not display in the displayed list under the drop down box. Your solution works but is not desirable because it displays the first option twice. Once in the drop down box and once in the list below the drop down box. But because it is the default selection, you cannot click it in the list.

Answer (score 0):

After working on this for a day and a half, I've finally come up with a solution.

I could not add styling directly to the list item, but I was able to add a class to the individual list item. Shown in VB:

CSS

```
.projdropdownclass {
display: none;
}
```

VB

```
    Private Sub ProjDropDownList_DataBound(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)            Handles ProjDropDownList.DataBound
    ProjDropDownList.Items(0).Attributes("class") = "projdropdownclass"
End Sub
```

The display: none; hides the first element in the drop down list.

[image]

I still think there should be a click event on the drop down box in VB and C#.

Hope this helps someone else.